# AutoMapper.CreateMapExpression<TDE, TD> throws "Argument types do not match" exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, automapper

I am developing a MVC web application using Razor View engine. 
I am using Entity Framework and using Database First architecture. Also using Automapper.Mapper for mapping Entities and poco Classes i.e. Models for View
I am struct at get data from database using EF.

I am get Error at the second line while executing  Mapper.CreateMapExpression

```
var detailCollection = GetRelatedCollection(entity);// Method to get data

            var selectExpression = Mapper.CreateMapExpression<TDE, TD>(); //select expression from entity

            return detailCollection.AsQueryable().Select(selectExpression);
```

Comment: You need to provide more context for you code, and a better description of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Stack trace would be lovely, perhaps the entire exception message?

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar error with the 'Project().To<T>(params string[])' overload.